# Controlar Dslr camera via web

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, coffeescript

Pessoal é o seguinte: Eu tenho uma aplicação web que eu gostaria de estar conectando uma câmera dslr(câmera fotográfica profissional) que ficasse exibindo a imagem ao vivo em um Canvas no html ou algo do tipo, e que literalmente pudesse controlar a câmera através da aplicação web, a Nikon e a Canon disponibilizam APIs para este tipo de automação, porem eu gostaria de saber se alguém tem ou conhece alguma biblioteca JavaScript que possa fazer este controle.

Desde já agradeço!

Obs: Estou utilizando .Net MVC6 como framework.